# tags: lista e list são sinônimas?

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

Veja as duas tags [list](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) e [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista) e suas descrições:

- [list](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list):

  > Esta tag é usado especificamente para o tipo de dados List que é uma
  >   forma de matriz dinâmica. Não deve ser usado para listas de HTML nem
  >   para listas em geral que tem suas próprias tags.
- [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista):

  > Uma lista é um tipo abstrato de dados que representa uma sequência de
  >   valores, em que o mesmo valor pode ocorrer mais de uma vez. As
  >   principais formas de implementar uma lista é através de um array
  >   (arranjo, vetor ou matriz unidimensional) ou uma lista encadeada.

Será que não deveriam ser sinônimas?

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Parece ser à primeira vista, mas eu tinha feito uma análise e fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Eu vejo pelas perguntas em `R` em que possuem o mesmo significado...

Comment: Mas tem que olhar tudo. Se acharem que é a mesma coisa precisaria decidir qual sobrevive. Mas tenho medo porque tem alguns usuários que acham que deve ter umas 3 ou 4 *tags* no total :)

Comment: claro... mas não consigo avaliar direito no resto.

Comment: Inclusive, nunca ouvi essa definição de list `tipo de dados List que é uma forma de matriz dinâmica. `

Comment: Algumas descrições são bem ruins. Precisa ver se faz sentido ter as duas ou não e depois arrumar a descrição.

Comment: Dei uma lida em quase todas as perguntas das duas tags. Ao meu ver não há diferença entre as perguntas de uma e da outra... Na tag `lista` as vezes aparecem perguntas mais teóricas sobre lista encadeada (que já possui uma tag especifica).. Enfim, não consigo entender porque deixar separado.

Answer (score 2):

É melhor deixar as duas. `Python` tem um objeto chamado `list`. Geralmente quando as perguntas se tratam especificamente de Python, eu costumo botar essa tag.

Lista pode ser uma penca de coisas. Talvez seja a descrição que não ajude. Ou também talvez seja a hora de pensar em criar a tag `python-list`.

Comment: Pensando especificamente em linguagens, essa seria uma boa alternativa. Em Delphi, por exemplo, existe o objeto chamado TList. No dia que precisar, caso não exista, eu vou criar este tag que, por si só já deixa claro que eu estou falando em uma lista do ponto de vista de programação (no caso, programação Delphi). Para linguagens que não usam essa nomenclatura diferenciada, usar um prefixo ou mesmo sufixo (list-python) seria uma boa alternativa

Comment: Diversas linguagens possuem objetos chamados `list`... Sobre o `python-list`, eu não sei se resolve. Pra mim seria a mesma coisa que criar uma tag para cada linguagem para o `ìf`, por exemplo: `c-if`, `python-if`, etc. Não sei se isso faz sentido. `list` em python é diferente de uma `list` em R, mas acredito que a principal diferença seja a implementação e não o conceito.. isso deve se repetir para as demias linguagens

Answer (score -1):

Pensando exclusivamente em tags e o que elas representam, penso que list e lista são a mesma coisa. Se levarmos em conta que estamos no SO em português o mais sensato seria manter o tag em português, contudo, como sabemos, o idioma da informática é o inglês, logo, algumas pessoas se sentem mais confortáveis em usar um tag chamado "list" ao invés de "lista", talvez com o intuito de atingir uma maior quantidade de pessoas.

Em suma, são sinônimos, mas se isso implica em escolher uma das duas, eu escolheria "list"

Comment: E se lista estiver sendo usada para listas em geral (e tem várias) e `List` estiver sendo usada para uma específica, para o tipo de dado da linguagem? Não digo que estejam sendo usadas corretamente, esse é outro problema, primeiro precisa ter certeza do uso, depois arrumar o uso errado.

Comment: Acredito que não vamos chegar a um consenso em relação a isso. Se deixarmos os dois tags, vão certamente usá-los como sinônimos, principalmente quando quiserem se referir a listas "computacionais", ao passo que quem quiser usar o tag para se referir a uma lista não computacional (genérica), usará certamente o tag em português

Comment: Talvez manter apenas o tag em português seja a solução, porque pensando no idioma inglês, não há diferença entre uma lista "computacional" e uma lista genérica. Neste caso se usa simplesmente LIST pra tudo. Sinceramente esta é uma questão bem filosófica :)